# I want to make new List every login

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an Android App that logins to a MySQL database and gets infomation from the database.
Every ID has some messages sent to that ID, and I make them to be showed in ListView.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> titleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleArray);
final ListView lvInbox = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvInbox);
lvInbox.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
```

[My Youtube Video Problem --> click to view and help me!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dra7EYEJBn8)

In that video, if I log in with username: 20081561 and I get 3 messages
I click back and log in with other username: 20083152 and I get 4 messages
Actually, the username 20083152 only have one messages and 3 others is 20081561's

If I build my app again and log in, it just shows only messages of the username logged in.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try reinitializing your `titleArray` on every `activity.onStart`, or clearing it up on every logout.

also you could check in your androidManifest.xml that these attributes are set properly:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
    [...]
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" [...]>
    [...]
</activity>
```